# linear equation of a plane from parametric equation

Tags: parametrization

How to find a linear equation of a plane that passes through the point $(6,0,-2)$ and contains the line with parametric equations $x=4-2t$, $y=3+5t$, $z=7+4t$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know how to find the equation of a plane containing $3$ points?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Yes. I think i need to find a plane from the parametric equations first, then use normal line  n=<a,b,c>, r=<x,y,z> and r_0=<x_0,y_0,z_0> and n \cdot (r-r_0)=0 to find the linear equation. But I have no idea how to convert the parametric equation to a plane.

Comment: Well, you can’t convert the parametric equation to a plane—it’s the equation of a line, after all. I assume that you know how to find the equation of a plane given three noncolinear points on it. Do that, using two points one the line. Those should be easy enough to find.

Comment: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32A/chap11/section5/717d31/717_31.html

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved!

Comment: you could compare your answer with mine (below)

Answer (score 0):

Three points in the plane are $(6,0,-2)$, $(4,3, 7$) [on the line when $t=0$],

and $(2,8,11)$ [on the line when $t=1$].

Their differences are vectors in the plane:

$(6,0,-2)-(4,3,7)=(2,-3,-9)$ and $(6,0,-2)-(2,8,11)=(4,-8,-13)$.

The cross-product of the two vectors $(2,-3,-9)\times(4,-8,-13)=(-33,-10,-4)$

is normal to the plane, and so is $(33,10,4)$.  So an equation of the plane is $33x+10y+4z=C$,

and you can figure out $C$ using any of the three points we know in the plane.  (I got $C=190$.)